# Direct code to loop a text input check until correct?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple little text adventure, DnD-style thing here as practice, but I have run into a problem that I can't for the life of me find a solution for.

I need to create a loop for when the user types the text response incorrectly because I don't want it responding to just anything the user types in and don't want to force the user to restart the entire program. I know about the do/while loop, but I have no idea how to implement it in a text input check because everyone uses it with numbers, not text.

Here's the code:

```
package drake;

import java.util.*;

public class drake {
public static void main(String[]args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);



    int ini_d = rand.nextInt((17 - 12) + 1) + 12;
    int ini_u = rand.nextInt((20 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    int cha_d = 16;
    int cha_u = 15;
    int r_d = rand.nextInt((20 - 11) + 1) + 11;
    int r_u = rand.nextInt((20 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    int hp_d = 50;
    int hp_u = 30;
    int dam_d = rand.nextInt((12 - 7) + 1) + 7;
    int dam_u = rand.nextInt((17 - 12) + 1) + 12;

    System.out.println("A young dragon towers over you, it's reptilian eyes digging into your very soul. It roars at you, posing a challenge.");
    System.out.println("Type 'roll' to roll for initiative.");
    String u_r1 = kb.next();

    while(true)
        if (u_r1.equalsIgnoreCase ("roll")) {

        System.out.println(ini_d);
        System.out.println(ini_u);
        break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your input was invald. Please try again.");
            //I need to give the user another chance to input text, and then direct the program to check it again and again until it's typed in correctly.
            return;
        }


    if (ini_d >= ini_u) {
        System.out.println("The dragon rushes towards you in an attempt to attack you.");
    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `String u_r1 = kb.next();` as the first statement in the while loop should work for you (since you `break` on encountering the right input).

```
while(true) {
    String u_r1 = kb.next();
    if (u_r1.equalsIgnoreCase("roll")) {
        System.out.println(ini_d);
        System.out.println(ini_u);
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your input was invald. Please try again.");
    }
}
//Rest of the code
```

Comment: Wow. It was staring me right in the face. Thanks so much.